# Will sharding allow for a much lower gas limit?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price, sharding

The current gas costs are for all nodes to process a transaction or contract function call. Once we have sharding, only a subset on the nodes(1 shard) will process that transaction/contract function call. So is it safe to assume that gas costs will basically be current gas costs/total number of shards?

Comment: Also asked by the OP at https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6689sq/will_sharding_allow_for_a_much_lower_gas_limit/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, assuming total tx's stay the same, then it will be something like current gas price / shards. I would assume that total tx's will increase however, when sharding goes into effect.

But yes, overall, as a scaling solution, sharding is meant to decrease load on each individual node, and decrease gas prices.

Answer (score 1):

The gas price will tend to be lower since more transactions can be processed per second, while with efficiency improvements such as EWasm and a [two layer account trie inside a single trie](https://ethresear.ch/t/a-two-layer-account-trie-inside-a-single-layer-trie/210/4) and a more efficient [blob serialization](https://ethresear.ch/t/blob-serialisation/1705) mechanism, the gas limit can increase.